# is there a way to say that for this method or for this block of code, i want you to use this namespace in order to avoid ambiguity?

Tags: c#, reference, using, ambiguous

Inside a C# method, is there a way to say that for this method or for this block of code, i want you to use this namespace in order to avoid ambiguity?

I am working on a project where i need to start using Telerik for my story, specifically Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.Workbook while continuing to also use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook in another procedure within the same file/class.

Now that many of the cells and methods from these 2 assemblies are the same, for telerik i started using the whole path when working with sheet, workbooks, cells etc...

Initially, i added a using telerik statement at the top of the class but that not only confused my code but also the one that was already there using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet. So i decided to remove the using telerik reference which saved me time from modifying all the old code too.

Ambiguous reference between DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook and Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.Workbook

My question: all my code where i need to work with Telerik's cells, sheet, rows, columns etc, is limited to 2-3 methods. Is there a way to create like a using block in a method so i wouldn't have to write Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.Workbook instead of just Workbook (when i get the ambiguity complaint)?

like maybe

```
using (Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.Workbook) {
 var workbook = new Workbook();
     ---- More code
 var row = new Row();
     ------ more code again
}
```

Comment: you can use [`global`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier) alias

Comment: Or use [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) to put the methods in a different file.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, you cannot specify namespace usage inside a method.
But asking this question tells me you are putting too much (different) things inside one class.

The solution is to split up the code into several classes, each having their own responsibility. Now each class can be `using` whatever namespaces they like, without interfering with the other code.